# How to return record base on page index parameter?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing

I'm working on index. I want to return a records based on the page index.

What I'm doing right now see below

First I create the table `Customers`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
(
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [ContactName] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ContactTitle] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Region] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
    [NewsLetters] [bit] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID) 
)
```

then I inserted 90 records and then I created the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Customers]
    @PageIndex int,
    @Pagesize int = 10  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Customers 
    ORDER BY CompanyName ASC 
        OFFSET @PageIndex ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT @Pagesize ROWS ONLY  

    RETURN  
END
```

Issue is when I execute the stored procedure, it does not display the proper data based on the index.

```
DECLARE @PageIndex int, @Pagesize int = 10  

EXEC Get_Customers 5,10        --here issue is displaying the data starting with the 5 to 14
```

When I execute the stored procedure like this, it must return the records 51 to 63

```
DECLARE @PageIndex int, @Pagesize int = 10  
EXEC Get_Customers 5,10
```

I'm referring to and learning from the below article.

Primary key create automatically clustered index.

https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-differenence-between-top-and-offset-fetch/

Which place need to correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic in the stored procedure is all wrong. You pass in `@PageIndex` and `@PageSize` - but you never **multiply** the two!

- When you want to get page no. 0 - you need to `OFFSET` by 0 rows.
- When you want to get page no. 5 - you need to `OFFSET` by **5 * 10 = 50** rows - by `@PageIndex * @PageSize` - **not just** by `@PageIndex` (that is only 5)

Try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Customers]
    @PageIndex int,
    @Pagesize int = 10  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Customers 
    ORDER BY CompanyName ASC 
        -- you need to offset by the **multiplication** of index and size!!!
        OFFSET @PageIndex * @PageSize ROWS    
        FETCH NEXT @Pagesize ROWS ONLY  

    RETURN  
END
```

With this, if you pass in `@PageIndex = 5` and `@PageSize = 10`, your code will first skip the first **5 * 10 = 50** rows, and then return the next **10** rows (rows no. 51 - 60).